# Estimating non-stationary Markov chain transition probabilities from data

Tags: r, markov-chain

I have some call centre outcome data: each person is called several times, and the result of the call is recorded as one of a few discrete outcomes ("no answer", "wrong number", "third party", "correct party", etc.).  The goal of the analysis is to try and work out how many times to call before giving up.

My current plan is to consider the outcomes as a Markov chain.  If I assume that the data represents a stationary state, then it is easy to [get the transition probabilities](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14360/estimating-markov-chain-probabilities).  The problem is, I don't believe that they are stationary: having "no answer" 20 times is a different situation to be in than having "no answer" once.

How do you calculate the transition probabilities if your data is non-stationary?

For bonus points, is there a function in R to do this?