# How to estimate Markov chain transition probabilities with partially observed data?

Tags: estimation, markov-process

Suppose that we have a time-homogeneous discrete-time Markov chain $(X_n)$.
We want to estimate the transition probabilities
$p_{ij} = \mathbb{P}[X_{n+1} = j \mid X_n = i]$.

In the case when we have full information,
e.g. we observe $(X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_N)$,
the maximum likelihood estimator is
$$ \hat{p}_{ij} = \frac{ n_{ij} }{ \sum_{k=1}^{m} n_{ik} }, $$
where $n_{ik}$ is the number of times that
the process moved from state $i$ to $k$.
(I took the expression above from https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/14361/22409)

Unfortunately, in my case we are not able to observe all the transitions.
For example, we may observe $X_1, X_6, X_{11}, X_{13}, X_{14}, X_{15}, \ldots$,
that is some of the states,
but the states that we observe are not regularly spaced.

I have two related questions:

1. Mathematically, how do we estimate the transition probabilities given such data observations?
2. What statistical software is available for estimating the transition probabilities?

Comment: Probably this paper is useful for you? https://link.springer.com/article/10.1057/jors.1995.55